# How does sklearn.cluster.KMeans handle an init ndarray parameter with missing centroids (available centroids less than n_clusters)?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

In Python sklearn KMeans ([see documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)), I was wondering what happens internally when passing an `ndarray` of shape (n, n_features) to the `init` parameter, When `n<n_clusters`

1. Does it drop the given centroids and just starts a kmeans++ initialization which is the default choice for the `init` parameter ? ([PDF paper kmeans++](http://ilpubs.stanford.edu:8090/778/1/2006-13.pdf)) ([How does Kmeans++ work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466323/how-exactly-does-k-means-work))
2. Does it consider the given centroids and fill **accordingly** the remaining centroids using kmeans++ ?
3. Does it consider the given centroids and fill the remaining centroids using random values ?

I didn't expect that this method returns no warning in this case. That's why I need to know how it manages this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give it a mismatching `init` it will adjust the number of clusters, as you can see from the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/cluster/k_means_.py#L739). This is not documented and I would consider it a bug.
I'll propose to fix it.

Comment: It would be interesting if it fills the remainig according to the Kmeans++ initialization method, considering the given centroids

Comment: We could add an option to do that, but it seems very specific. In general, this is probably a sign of an error in user code. We could add an "fill_clusters='kmeans++'" option that by default raises an error. But I'm not sure it is worth adding this code. You can easily implement it yourself, though.

Comment: How might you implement this? [Link to relevant question and background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921503/define-k-1-cluster-centroids-sklearn-kmeans)