# ClusterR - optimal_init method

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

The documentation of the initialization methods for clustering using ClusterR is very enigmatic. Are you able to post a reference to a paper describing optimal_init method?

This is what is stated officially:

**optimal_init:** this initializer adds rows of the data incrementally, while checking that they do not already exist in the centroid-matrix

Comment: Maybe it will help to [check source code](https://github.com/mlampros/ClusterR/blob/master/src/kmeans_miniBatchKmeans_GMM_Medoids.cpp#L130).

Answer (score 0):

The initializers used in the *KMeans_rcpp* and *MiniBatchKmeans* of the ClusterR package are :

- *random* (random selection of data rows as initial centroids),
- *kmeans++* (Reference : http://theory.stanford.edu/~sergei/papers/kMeansPP-soda.pdf AND http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466323/how-exactly-does-k-means-work),
- *quantile_init* (it uses quantiles and cumulative distances to pick the initial centroids) and
- *optimal_init* (it adds observations to the centroids incrementally by first checking that they do not already exist in the picked centroids).

I added the last two (*quantile_init* and *optimal_init*) in the package, because I found out after testing in various data sets that they give similar (or better) results (using validation metrics) and/or run faster. They are both experimental and (you are right) in the next version of the package I'll add a note in the documentation details. You can see the rcpp code of [quantile_init](https://github.com/mlampros/ClusterR/blob/master/src/utils_rcpp.cpp#L376) and 
[optimal_init](https://github.com/mlampros/ClusterR/blob/master/src/utils_rcpp.cpp#L438) in the package repository.